# LARAVEL 4 и JSON

Tags: json, php

У меня есть класс `GpsController`, в нем я описал метод  `GPSOnline`
На выходе у меня должно быть:

```
[{"login":"199","ch":"1","poz":"99","la":"48.303017","lo":"38.041583"},{"login":"370","ch":"3","poz":"70","la":"48.297291","lo":"38.0153"},{"login":"399","ch":"3","poz":"99","la":"48.308815","lo":"38.02129"},{"login":"1209","ch":"1","poz":"209","la":"48.31639","lo":"37.964965"},{"login":"122","ch":"1","poz":"22","la":"48.338839","lo":"37.97747"},{"login":"3142","ch":"3","poz":"142","la":"48.305961","lo":"38.033485"},{"login":"1284","ch":"1","poz":"284","la":"48.34223","lo":"37.97"}]
```

Вот непосредственно сам метод:

```
public function GPSOnline () {
    $gpsonline=File::get( Config::get('app.driverspath'));
    $fstep = explode("|", $gpsonline);
        foreach($fstep as $k => $v){
            if(strlen($v)>0){
                $sstep [] = explode(",", $v);
            }
        }
    $array = array();
    foreach ($sstep as $v){
        $tmp['ch'] = substr($v[0],0,1);
        $tmp['poz'] = substr($v[0],1);
        $tmp['la'] = $v[1];
        $tmp['lo'] = $v[2];
        $array[] = $tmp;
    } 
    // echo json_encode($array);
    return Response::json(array($array));
}
```

Но почему то мой код не работает
Контроллер в роуте прописан, что не так?

Comment: У вас после `return` идут операторы:

`          return Response::json(array($array));`
`          $validator = Validator::make($array);`
`          $messages = $validator->messages();`

Comment: валидаторы удалил и в чем же ошибка с методом  Response::json?

Comment: @CBETOBuT - А ошибки то вываливаются?

Comment: Да Controller method not found. 
Хотя роут до контроллера прописан

Comment: что написано в рутере?
текст ошибки?

Answer (score 1):

Проверяйте всегда маршрут в роуте! если он корректен то все будет работать!